# regex vim multiple characters in search, multiple characters in replace

Tags: regular-expression

what is the most efficient regex (vim/perl) to replace 100 'a' characters with 300 'b' characters. I can get the search part correct :%s/a\{100}/?????? but the 'replace' portion eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `:%s/a\{100}/\=repeat('b',100)/`

Comment: that does it. i'd been using the search form in the replace portion and just did not work. i don't know how to mark this as the correct answer, but it does exactly what i was looking for. thanks.

Comment: @iohannfust click the greyed-out check mark next to the answer to mark it as “accepted”